# Multi-level dropdown Navigation Bar is reset based on few actions on page only in Chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, servlets, navigation, struts

I am having trouble figuring out this one issue that occurs through out the application. There is 3 level drop-down navigation bar in the top to navigate through different modules of application. Based on chosen menu item the landing page will display respective details on the bottom. Not all but For only few actions triggered on the page user is at, the navigation bar gets reset to default mode. This only happens in chrome browser. But it is fine in IE, Firefox and safari browsers.

[Here is the image to show working menu bar before clicking on some buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72jq.png)

[Here is the image to show that menu bar is reset to default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igtg.png)

About the application itself technology stack is really old like 25 year old technology using Java (recently upgraded to Java 8), jsp, struts 0.x, servlets 1.x, ibatis etc. Like any other application that lived that long has different technologies built into it over the period. This behavior occurs only in chrome browser and when the application is behind proxy. Because in local deployment it works fine both in chrome and IE browser. I know I am asking a needle be found in hay stack, but I am at wits end as I have looked a lot of code and logs to figure if any session object being set or removed that can cause this issue. I know my case is kind of unique but I am, at this point, willing to go in any direction I am pointed to.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's nothing here anyone could use to even begin to help.

Comment: I assumed it is not enough and this issue is very specific to our application. I cannot add code as I do not know where it is happening. Thank you for letting me know. I will close the question as I do not hope to get any resolution.